# Draw padding for convex hull java

Tags: java, convex-hull

I already got the set of points that define that convex hull. How can I add a kind of padding to them, so that all the points is inside? I am trying to draw the red line

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I'd try to create an outline offsetted from a polygon by distance *d:*

- Consider a straight line segment between each pair of consecutive points (the original convex hull).
- Offset each segment by *d* along its perpendicular to the outside. The offsetted segments have gaps between ends.
- For each pair of consecutive offsetted line segments, add a segment of a circle such that it both segments are its tangents; its radius should be *d*. It's easy to do: draw perpendiculars at the ends of both segments; their intersection is the center of the circle.

Now you have a sequence of interspersed straight lines and arcs. It should be the outline you're seeking.

To work comfortably, you'd need these functions:

- Find the [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#General_(or_standard)_form) of the straight line by two points (store it as an object with 3 float fields);
- Find an equation of a perpendicular line by a line equation and a point;
- Find the point of [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Using_homogeneous_coordinates) of two lines, given their equations.

Comment: In the step 2, how can I find positive or negative offset is pointing to the "outside"?

Comment: You have a _convex_ hull. Any other point in it lies in the inside direction, relative to a segment between two consecutive points. Also, many algorithms produce the points in a particular order, so the enclosed area is always to the left (or always to the right) of a segment.